# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Screen Flickering Lenovo Yoga S740 Geforce MX250

Tags: 20.04, nvidia-geforce

Since the update to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is my screen flickering every couple of seconds.

I have a Lenovo S740 with i7 Ice Lake and Nvidia Geforce MX250.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I solved the problem. I figured out that the screen flickering only appears when on battery. Uninstalling tlp solved my problem. It might have been just a tlp settings problem and I tried a couple of settings but none helped, so I uninstalled it.

Uninstall tlp:

```
sudo apt-get purge tlp
```

Cheers
Kait